# SushiSwap Fork reverting at createPair()

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have forked sushiswap recently from the [repo](https://github.com/sushiswap/sushiswap). I am getting the following error when calling `createPair()` from `UniswapV2Factory.sol` during my deployment, the code has not been touched and I have no idea where I am going wrong.

The error:
`Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

The deployment:

```js
// Uniswap
const Factory = artifacts.require('Uniswapv2/UniswapV2Factory.sol');

// WETH
const WETH = artifacts.require('WETH.sol');

// Testing
const MockERC20 = artifacts.require('MockERC20.sol');

module.exports = async function(deployer, network, accounts) {
    const [admin, _] = accounts;

    // Test Tokens
    const tokenA = await MockERC20.new('TokenA', 'TKA', web3.utils.toWei('100000'));
    const tokenB = await MockERC20.new('TokenB', 'TKB', web3.utils.toWei('100000'));

    // Uniswap factory
    await deployer.deploy(Factory, admin);
    const factory = await Factory.deployed();

    await factory.createPair(tokenA.address, tokenB.address);

};
```

CreatePair function:

```js
function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external override returns (address pair) {
        require(tokenA != tokenB, 'UniswapV2: IDENTICAL_ADDRESSES');
        (address token0, address token1) = tokenA < tokenB ? (tokenA, tokenB) : (tokenB, tokenA);
        require(token0 != address(0), 'UniswapV2: ZERO_ADDRESS');
        require(getPair[token0][token1] == address(0), 'UniswapV2: PAIR_EXISTS'); // single check is sufficient
        bytes memory bytecode = type(UniswapV2Pair).creationCode;
        bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1));
        assembly {
            pair := create2(0, add(bytecode, 32), mload(bytecode), salt)
        }
        UniswapV2Pair(pair).initialize(token0, token1); //<-- this is causing the error
        getPair[token0][token1] = pair;
        getPair[token1][token0] = pair; // populate mapping in the reverse direction
        allPairs.push(pair);
        emit PairCreated(token0, token1, pair, allPairs.length);
    }
```

I have deduced that the error is happening here `UniswapV2Pair(pair).initialize(token0, token1);` but as to why I have no idea.

Any insights would be much appreciated!
James

Comment: did you manage to sort out this issue? I've run into the same thing

Comment: Yes I did actually!

You need to find the `pairFor` function in UniswapV2Library.sol.

You then to replace the hex used here with the one generated by your UniswapV2Pair.
                      `hex'<YOUR HEX STRING HERE>' // init code hash`

You can find your bytecode at this line in UniswapV2Factiry.sol

`bytes memory bytecode = type(UniswapV2Pair).creationCode;`

I emitted that out to myself and then replaced the hex code and it worked.... I think haha... it was a while ago, but I believe that is the issue :D

Answer (score 1):

Check your truffle config. If you are deploying to testnet or local add the flag

`skipDryRun: true`

I've deployed the contract to both ropsten and mainnetusing this flag (note: this is default on mainnet)

Comment: I’m using hardhat instead of truffles. How can I set this flag ? Any idea  thx